# macOS Photos.app - Names Missing on Shared Albums

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, sharing, high-sierra

Recently the names from users of my shared album have disappeared from the activity feeds (See picture) - this has only happened on the desktop, both the iPhone and iPad are fine.

Just updated to High Sierra and hoped the issue would fix itself - but nope, still a problem. Any ideas? Searching for answers hasn't revealed anything.

[image: My name appears, others don't]

Comment: Please try these steps and report back: 1. In Photos.app in your Mac go to Photos > Settings > iCloud and uncheck 'iCloud Photo Sharing'. 2. Wait about a minute for the changes to apply. 3. Quit Photos.app and restart your Mac. 4. Open Photos.app and turn on 'iCloud Photo Sharing'.

Comment: That fixed it! Which is annoying as I've already tried that in the past... :/ If you put that as a proper answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try these steps and report back:

1. In Photos.app in your Mac go to Photos > Settings > iCloud and uncheck 'iCloud Photo Sharing'.
2. Wait about a minute for the changes to apply.
3. Quit Photos.app and restart your Mac.
4. Open Photos.app and turn on 'iCloud Photo Sharing'.